# How to formulate the convex hull which is a regular polygon on the complex plane

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-hull

Suppose that I have a convex regular polygon with $k$ vertices on the complex plane, and the first vertex lies on the positive real axis. Is there a neat way to formulate the convex hull with the shape of regular polygon and make it acceptable for CVX solver?
I could take the intersection of the half-spaces of each side of the polygon, but it seems to be a little bit complicated, when $k$ grows large.

Comment: Do you have a convex polygon or you just have its vertices? Are you vertices equidistant from (0, 0)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have a convex polygon. Suppose the radius is $r$, and the first vertex will be at $(r,0)$. Right now I am using the intersection of halfplanes of each side of the polygon to represent the convex hull. As the $K$ normally is not that large, maybe it's fine that I continue to use it.

Comment: I don't understand, if you already have a convex polygon why do you need to compute its convex hull?

Comment: Also, since you have the number of vertices and all lie at a distance $r$ from the origin and know the position for the first one, you can determine analytically all the positions and connectivities.

Comment: Maybe I didn't demonstrate my problem quite well. Yes, I can use the halfplanes of each side to express all the points that are in the interior and on the boundary of this polygon. I am just wondering whether there is a simpler way to formulate it. Sorry for not state my problem clearly.

Comment: But, what is your input data? That's the part I haven't figured out yet

Comment: The input data is the point in this polygon, which is a complex number. Is that what you refer to? I am not sure if I get you question right.

Comment: With a single point is not enough to define a polygon so I'm guessing that you have more input data.

Comment: Yes, I mean all the interior points and the points on the boundary, which are the intersection of all the halfplanes. Sorry for not clarifying myself clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a general set of points and want to compute its convex hull, the best option is to use an algorithm that is already implemented and tested in a library. [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org/) is probably the best option, they have implementations for [Python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy.spatial.ConvexHull) and Matlab.

Suppose you know that your boundary points are at a distance $r$ from the origin in the plane. In that case, you can filter them according to their distance from $(0, 0)$ and join them according to the angle with the horizontal — that you can compute using the function $\operatorname{atan2}$.